# How do I run a command without root properties

Tags: root

Say I am logged in root, and some commands don't let me to run them in root. I tried to login different accounts, but I'm not able to do such a thing.

How can I execute such command (logged in root) without the root properties?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
su -c "command and args" username
```

Comment: Necessary warning: You should not use shell as root unless in extremely specific conditions.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo -u <user> -H <command>`